# Plotting the velocity and acceleration vector of a particle

Tags: animation

I want to create an animation containing a particle moving along a circle with tangential speed 2t and its normal and tangential acceleration vectors which I calculated to be a(T)=2 and a(N)=4t^2.

The best I could do was to find code on wolfram and modify it a little, but I was unable to plot the increasing normal acceleration in the animation. Here is the code.

```
p = ParametricPlot[
      {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
      AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
      PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {-6, 6}}
    ];
b[t_] = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, t]];
c[t_] = {Cos[t], Sin[t]};
Animate[
  Show[
    p, 
    Graphics[{
      Locator[c[t]], 
      Thick, Blue, Arrow[{c[t], c[t] + b[t][[1]]}],
      Red,         Arrow[{c[t], c[t] + b[t][[2]]}]
    }],
    ImageSize -> Medium
  ], 
  {{t, 0}, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

How can I modify it to include the increasing normal acceleration vector?

Comment: I said the tangential speed is $2t$, where $t$ is time. It is not constant.

Comment: What is the particle motion equation? What are the accelerations of a(N) and a(T) come from? Because {Cos[t], Sin[t]} is only a unit speed motion.

Comment: If speed is $2t$, perhaps you meant the parametrization to be $(\cos t^2, \sin t^2)$?

Answer (score 2):

```
viv = {Cos[t], Sin[t], 0} &; 
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[viv[t], t]] // Simplify;
{tangent, normal, binormal} = 
  Map[Arrow[{viv[t], viv[t] + #}] &, basis];
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[viv[s], {s, 0, 4 Pi}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, White}], 
   Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, tangent, Red, normal, Purple, binormal, 
     Gray, Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}], PlotRange -> 2] // Evaluate, {t, 
  0, 4 Pi, Appearance -> {"Open", "Labelled"}}]
```

[image: solution]

This as simple as using [`FrenetSerretSystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html) but understanding it. I just did put the given solution of motion into the example on that documentation page. Three linear independent vectors can only coexist in 3D. In 2D one of them is for sure linear dependent of the two others.

I left the sphere in the animation to remind of 3D ahead of the coordinate system.